# Failing to extract a tar/bz2 file

Tags: linux, debian, tar, bzip2

File in question is http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/detail?name=wkhtmltopdf-0.10.0_rc2-static-i386.tar.bz2

```
meder@pc:~$ tar -xvjf wkhtmltopdf-0.10.0_rc2-static-i386.tar.bz2 
bzip2: (stdin) is not a bzip2 file.
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors
```

I tried to `unzip` it as well, and I tried a various slew of commands to no avail on my Debian box which has no GUI.

I downloaded this on my local desktop ( Ubuntu ) and was able to easily extract w/ my mouse so I'm not exactly sure what the extractor did differently...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does `file` tell you? It may have been uncompressed why you downloaded it. If so, it's just not compressed at all.

Comment: wkhtmltopdf-0.10.0_rc2-static-i386.tar.bz2: bzip2 compressed data, block size = 900k

Comment: interesting.. i just did `tar -xvf` and that seemed to extract it....

Comment: Son of a.. I seemed to have `wget`'d a 404/hotlink page instead of the actual file. Thanks and accepting asap.